# Why getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); doesn't work in landscape mode?

Tags: android, input, resize, landscape

I have the following code in my Main Activity's onCreate:

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I have the following code in my layout-land/main.xml

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi</EditText>
```

Why softinput is superimposed on top of the UI but does not change its size in landscape mode?
How can I do to make an UI with softinput behave in landscape mode the same as in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Divers it may be that fact you are missing a closing quotation mark on your IME options declaration in your manifest.xml.

Hope this helps !!

Doug

Comment: Sorry just started actually using this site and I always answer as many unanswered questions as I can they should probably remove a question after three years.... anyway sorry wasnt sooner